# How to avoid a cotton sweater to leave cotton on T-shirts?

Tags: clothing

I have recently acquired a **sweater**, the problem is that the inside in composed of **cotton** and as it's new, I always have little pieces of coton **remaining on T-shirts** I wear with, which is annoying.

I tryed waching him by hand and at the washing machine severals time but the problem remain. Do you have some tips or life-hack related solution for this case?

*Here is the label if that may help:*

[image]

Comment: This won't solve the problem, but to remove the tiny piece of cotton from your t-shirts I recommend a lint roller. In case you are unfamiliar with that, it's a wide role of tape that is "inside out", with the sticky side on the outside, with a handle that allows you to roll it across fabric to pick up lint. That's my favorite Lifehacks tool, after duct tape.

Answer (score 1):

Lint and fuzz tend to appear on clothes, especially those made of natural materials like cotton or wool, due to a couple reasons. One common cause is the short and crinkly characteristics of the staple fiber, which create lots of little hooks for grabbing onto stray lint (almost like Velcro).

Here are a few easy solutions to this issue:

- Use a lint brush or roller on the affected area to quickly pick loose
  fuzz
- Wash your item (no detergent) with a cup of distilled white
  vinegar which relaxes the fibers and looses the lint
- Use anti-static
  or anti-cling spray to neutralize any static charge in the garment. Even small amounts of static charge will cause fibers to stick
  together

Or you could always just wear a t-shirt that is the same color as your sweater, then your lint will effectively be invisible!