# T Shirt Microfibres/Lint

Tags: cleaning, clothing, dust, house-cleaning

Not sure if anybody can help with this, but I have some basic t-shirts from H&M and Uniqlo and both seem to produce an unreasonably large amount of what I can only describe as small microfibres.

The t-shirts were like this from the moment I've bought them and continue to shed these microfibres now.

You see them best when in direct light but also out of direct light the problem is so pervasive that these tiny microfibres begin to leave a layer of what I believed was dust on TV screen, laptop screen, phone screen, shelves etc.

Literally anytime you move you see a cloud of these tiny fibres coming off of the fabric.

My question - has anybody else had a similar experience? I appreciate that clothes do lint, however this issue seems to be excessive. Is it perhaps just the quality of the t shirts?

Any advice/experience/thoughts you have would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks

Comment: [Related](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/20455/how-to-avoid-a-cotton-sweater-to-leave-cotton-on-t-shirts). Worth to try the advise given in the answer there.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, it's the quality of the shirts. I had it before with cheap polyester shirts. If it's more like dust and less like lint, it helped for me to put the shirts together with microfiber cloths in a dryer. The "dust" was afterwards attached to the microfiber, I guess due to its static. Some websites also suggested to wash them with white vinegar, but I personally did not try it.

For actual lint, like little "wool" balls, my mum taught me to shave the clothes by simply using a disposable razor, or you can also buy lint and pilling remover.
Just slide carefully over the fabric with the shaver, this will remove it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Nice first answer, kudos! Just curious, why are you using different name/profile data for each site?

Comment: Thank you :) usually, I always use Hannah, this was more by editing it in a rush :D The different profile data because I try to make it more matching for each site. I studied for example German linguistics, which is useful information for the German site but everyone else prob doesn't care :D Would you recommend using one long profile instead? Thought then people might not read it.

Comment: That's an excellent point, I admit never really giving it much thought. The problem is it becomes a real hassle to maintain, e.g. if you want to add Twitter link, you'll have to add it to each site manually as copying to all sites would also change all the other fields. But yes, having custom profile with matching description for each site is ideal, cheers! Anyway, wanted also to invite you to [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), lots of friendly folk in there, who would love to discuss anything. :)

Answer (score 0):

You might get better performance from the shirts by changing the way they are laundered.

Different fabrics respond better to different washing techniques. Read and heed the washing instructions for clothes.

If you used hot water washing the shirts, try using cold water or vise-versa.

Further, try to use as little detergent as possible to get the job done. Add only as much detergent as you need to produce a few bubbles during the agitation phase—not a foam of bubbles.

Good luck.